# A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property - while creating a list

Tags: c#

Getting an error while creating a list of parts. Error occur at parts.add. It says

> A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property

Code:

```
List<Part> parts = new List<Part>() { 
    // Add parts to the list.
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "crank arm", PartId = 1234});
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "chain ring", PartId = 1334 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "regular seat", PartId = 1434 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "banana seat", PartId = 1444 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "cassette", PartId = 1534 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "shift lever", PartId = 1634 });
}

public class Part
{
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public string PartId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is your class static?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call Add() as part of an initializer.  Change your code to:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    List parts = new List();

    // Add parts to the list.
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "crank arm", PartId = 1234});
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "chain ring", PartId = 1334 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "regular seat", PartId = 1434 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "banana seat", PartId = 1444 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "cassette", PartId = 1534 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "shift lever", PartId = 1634 });
}

public class Part
{
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public string PartId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to invoke `Add` method to add items when using collection initializer ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)), just list them with commas as you would do with arrays, and you are done.

```
List parts = new List<Part>() {
    // Add parts to the list.
    new Part() { PartName = "crank arm", PartId = 1234},
    new Part() { PartName = "chain ring", PartId = 1334 },
    new Part() { PartName = "regular seat", PartId = 1434 },
    new Part() { PartName = "banana seat", PartId = 1444 },
    new Part() { PartName = "cassette", PartId = 1534 },
    new Part() { PartName = "shift lever", PartId = 1634 }
}
```